# jQuery Hidden div on start of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I would like to ask what's the possible problem with my website. I have a contact form below that will open a pop up. That pop up is already set as hidden in jQuery (class name is .overlay) but when the website loads, the pop up is showing itself for very small amount of time. I would like it to be completely hidden on the start of the site.

[MY WEBSITE](http://www.designsbyps.com)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to keep the css of `.overlay` to `display:none`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the css version:

```
.overlay{
  display:none
}
```

This way, as the page loads it is hidden at the beginning and you can change that with Jquery.

The problem is that, Jquery tends to take time to load. So instead, keep that in the CSS and keep it in the head tag, so it would get processed first.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, I include a style="display: none" within the DIV to avoid those times where JQuery takes a few moments to load.

```
<div style="display: none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use `display:none;` for not displaying a element on the webpage or you could use `visibility: none;` but display works better.

```
<div style="display: none;">

  Hello World

</div>
```

This is the style

```
.overlay {
    display:none
 }
```

This would put the visibility to none where it would not show on the webpage but also the space will remove, `visibility: hidden;` would only take it away but not take away the space.

Or you want to do it in Jquery here is the code:

```
$(".overlay").hide();
```

You just have to use `hide();`

Jquery takes alot of time to load. So instead, please keep that in the CSS and keep that in the head tag.